# jquery mobile button icons-36-white.png shows wrong icon

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons

My problem in short is that when i ovveride .ui-icon background image url() to icons-36-white.png it returns ( gear ) for data-icon="home", ( - ) for data-icon="delete" and so forth for all icons, they are mismatched!

I tried to change the url to url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/icons-36-white.png), yet it still gives me this funky issue!!

Please advice...

**html:**

```
<a href="#welPage" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

**css:**

```
#mainNav .ui-icon {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    /*background-image: url(../themes/images/icons-36-white.png);*/
    background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/icons-36-white.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place it in your css file...

```
 .ui-icon-plus, .ui-icon-minus, .ui-icon-delete, .ui-icon-arrow-r,
    .ui-icon-arrow-l, .ui-icon-arrow-u, .ui-icon-arrow-d, .ui-icon-check,
    .ui-icon-gear, .ui-icon-refresh, .ui-icon-forward, .ui-icon-back,
    .ui-icon-grid, .ui-icon-star, .ui-icon-alert, .ui-icon-info, .ui-icon-home, .ui-icon-bars, .ui-icon-edit,
    .ui-icon-search, .ui-icon-searchfield:after, 
    .ui-icon-checkbox-off, .ui-icon-checkbox-on, .ui-icon-radio-off, .ui-icon-radio-on {
        background-image: url(images/icons-36-white.png);
        -moz-background-size: 864px 18px;
        -o-background-size: 864px 18px;
        -webkit-background-size: 864px 18px;
        background-size: 864px 18px;
    }
    .ui-icon-alt .ui-icon {
        background-image: url(images/icons-36-black.png);
    }
    .ui-icon-plus {
        background-position:    0 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-minus {
        background-position:    -36px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-delete {
        background-position:    -72px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-arrow-r {
        background-position:    -108px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-arrow-l {
        background-position:    -144px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-arrow-u {
        background-position:    -179px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-arrow-d {
        background-position:    -215px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-check {
        background-position:    -252px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-gear {
        background-position:    -287px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-refresh {
        background-position:    -323px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-forward {
        background-position:    -360px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-back {
        background-position:    -395px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-grid {
        background-position:    -431px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-star {
        background-position:    -467px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-alert {
        background-position:    -503px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-info {
        background-position:    -538px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-home {
        background-position:    -575px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-search,
    .ui-icon-searchfield:after {
        background-position:    -611px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-checkbox-on {
        background-position:    -647px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-checkbox-off {
        background-position:    -683px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-radio-on {
        background-position:    -718px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-radio-off {
        background-position:    -754px 50%;
    }
    .ui-icon-bars {
        background-position:    -788px 50%;

    }.ui-icon-edit {
        background-position:    -824px 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: it fixed the mapping issue greatly!, but the button size is still small! you maybe thought that i want an HD trick for button images, but what i wanted actually was to make an icon 36x36 instead of 18x18
Thanks for the effort anyway =)

Comment: What is 864px?? for background width? can you please tell me what does this number represents exactly?